# Would this be considered simple harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

If a small creature moves in a vertical circle, will its shadow formed on a horizontal plane, because of the sun, move in a simple harmonic motion?

I'm considering it to be a small circle so that the altitude of the sun doesn't have any role in this. What I had in mind was that the shadow would be longer for the bottom point of the circle, and shorter for the top (imagining the sun to be higher than the creature and horizontal plane, at some angle).

My question is, can the length of the shadow be considered as a simple harmonic motion with the mean point being that length of the shadow, which is exactly half of the shadow formed at the bottom point (or double the shadow formed at the top point).

What I deduced is:

1. the length is changing periodically;
2. however, there isn't any 'force' acting on it;
3. and there would be two mean points because the length would be the same for two diametrically opposite points.

It'd look something like this, from what I could make out:

[image: It'd look something like this, from what I could make out.]

This is the best I could draw, but as is evident, the angle formed by the rays and the creature at the top is smaller than that at the bottom, so the shadow lengths should also differ accordingly.

Comment: Hi Shreya, welcome to PSE. What do you think the shadow would look like, maybe bearing in mind the changing altitude of the sun, if its a small creature and a large circle?

Comment: @User171879, edited the question explaining what I'm imagining. :)

Comment: I am dumb, admittedly, but if ever a question needed a picture maybe showing lines projecting from the circular motion to the shm motion, this is the one.

Comment: @User171879, hahaha, more likely that I'm bad at explaining. Added a figure. I hope I'm more clear now?

Comment: This construction has a name: "the reference circle'' and it is sometimes used to motivate the functional form of the position, velocity, and acceleration of simple harmonic motion for students without calculus. To be absolutely correct, however, your diagram needs the incident light to be parallel (not changing in angle as the motion proceeds). As a practical matter using sunlight achieves this, but as drawn your diagram shows a geometry in which the projection's motion would not be sinusoidal.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly note, the term 'simple harmonic motion' usually includes a dynamical component, i.e. it's not just that something is moving sinusoidally but that there is a force-proportional-to-the-displacement that acts on it to achieve that sinusoidal movement.

Down at that level of subtlety in the definitions, to be honest, there aren't any hard lines, and both conventions could work depending on context.

- If an author claimed that this projection is an example of simple harmonic motion, I would find that acceptable.
- If another author claimed that this is only describable as sinusoidal motion because of the lack of simple-harmonic dynamics, then I would also find it OK.

Those authors would then need to follow through on those conventions (i.e. the second author would then need to apply that dynamics requirement on all further ocurrences of, and the first author would be obliged to accept all sinusoidal motion as simple-harmonic) but other than that, I wouldn't see any more problems.

Because, honestly, this isn't that important in the grand scheme of things ;-). Language is important, but only insofar as it is not create ambiguities and it correctly communicates the information it needs to.

Comment: Okay, say I do consider it an example of simple harmonic motion. What about the fact that it would have two mean points? Is that possible in a case of simple harmonic motion? If yes, can you mention another example?

Comment: What do you mean by "two mean points"?

Comment: There would be two mean points because the length of the shadow would be the same for the set of diametrically opposite points which are at the same height (as they'd make the same angle with the sun rays), correct?

Comment: No. The mean point is the central point of the motion. Nothing you're saying (in the comments) is specific to your situation - it would also apply to the sinusoidal motion of a mass attached to a spring.

Comment: Then what should be the mean point of this situation?

Comment: As I said, the central point of the motion - the midpoint between the two extremes. I won't answer further comments on this thread, though.

Comment: Oh wait, never mind. I think I was confusing the motion of the creature with the shadows' lengths. The two points that I previously mentioned, they'd be different if we looked at the creature's motion. However, if we look at the shadow's length, they're the same. Which further brings us to the conclusion that the time period of this SHM (involving the lengths of the shadows) is half the time that the creature would take to complete one revolution. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Shreya This comment thread is not for back-and-forth; if you want that kind of interaction, take it to the [site chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) (after [20 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)).